# Add SSH action in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I want to create PhpStorm action that will run local SSH command. Is that possible?

I want to bind it to some hotkey inside PhpStorm not to type my command every time in terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes -- you can create **SSH External Tools entry** that will execute your command over SSH connection. Once crated you can assign custom shortcut to such tool in `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`.

Keep in mind that such command will be run in separate SSH connection and not in your current terminal.

Few links to read more (general concept / exact steps):

- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+External+Tools+in+PhpStorm
- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+PhpStorm+built-in+SSH+terminal+and+remote+SSH+external+tools